# How to send an HTTP Request by using name of the Enum in query parameter

Tags: http, .net-core, enums, json.net, query-string

I tried to pass enum value as a query param for Post request but it does not accept the value? When I try to send a request from Swagger it does not even send the request.

**NOTE: I use Newtonsof.Json library and I also added configuration to the startup**

```
services.AddMvc(opt =>
{
    ...
})
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
     options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
     options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
});
```

```
public enum CardBrand
{
     [Description("MASTER")]
     MASTER,
     [Description("PAYPAL")]
     PAYPAL,
     [Description("VISA")]
     VISA
}
```

```
[HttpPost("{orderId}")]        
public async Task<ResponseModel<bool>> RandomTask(string orderId, CardBrand cardBrand)
{
    return await _orderService.UpdatePayment(orderId, cardBrand);
}
```

[Swagger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbs37.png)

Comment: Just a friendly note-- if you solved your own question it is preferred that you add your solution as an answer rather than editing the question itself to say "solved".  You can also mark your own answer as accepted (after a short wait period) and the system will know you are no longer looking for a solution.

Comment: I did not know this, thanks for informing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger has the DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings function which is available on version 5.0.0. I solved my problem by using this function. I hope it works for others too